Can´t use integers in Pi4J
I just write this simple code
package com.ultimatum;

import com.pi4j.Pi4J;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.digital.DigitalOutput;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.digital.DigitalState;

public class Ultimatum {
    private static final int PIN_LED = 22;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var pi4j = Pi4J.newAutoContext();
        var ledConfig = DigitalOutput.newConfigBuilder(pi4j)
                .id("my-dout")
                .name("My LED")
                .address(PIN_LED)
                .shutdown(DigitalState.LOW)
                .initial(DigitalState.HIGH);
        var led = pi4j.create(ledConfig);
    }
}


And the IDE says that PIN_LED must be an Integer value, which is not true since in the Minimal Example it's exactly written like that. Furthermore, when I try to convert PIN_LED to an Integer it says "Cannot access java.lang.Integer"
Here's the pom I used
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.ultimatum</groupId>
    <artifactId>Ultimatum</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.pi4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>pi4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.pi4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>pi4j-plugin-raspberrypi</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.pi4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>pi4j-plugin-gpiod</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>

